# Скрытие полей в Contact Form 7 если пользователь не авторизован

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Доброго времеин суток друзья, на днях столкнулся с такой задачей, мне нужно делать кнопку для отправки формы disable если пользователь не авторизован и подпись типа после авторизации вам будет дана возможность отправить форму.(Использую cms wordpress, плагин формы contact form 7)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения submit-кнопки можете попробовать добавить в файл function.php вашей темы такой код:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'hide_submit_for_guests' );
function hide_submit_for_guests( $content ) {
    $s_button = 'код кнопки submit';
    $ds_button = 'код неактивной кнопки submit';
    $content = preg_replace( $s_button, $ds_button, $content);

    return $content;    
}
```

Сразу хочу отметить, что это затронет сразу все формы Contact Form 7 на вашем сайте.

Чтобы скрывать любой контент, в том числе и форму целиком, можете использовать следующий подход. В `function.php` вашей темы добавляете такой код:

```
add_shortcode('members_only', 'sc_members_only');

function sc_members_only( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() ) {
    return do_shortcode($content);
  } else {
    return $atts['text'];
  }
}
```

В нужном месте делаете так:

```
[members_only text="после авторизации вам будет дана возможность отправить форму"]
  Shortcode вашей формы Contacts Form 7
  (или любой другой контент для зарегистрированных пользователей)
[/members_only]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)  Добавил условия для проверки и все огонь!